# Row Binding Separate Database Queries

Tags: r, dplyr, dbi, rbind

I'm working with two similar sets of data in a database. I've been querying them using dplyr syntax (e.g.,

```
q1 <- tbl(con, "data")
q2 <- tbl(con, "data2"))
```

, but I can't find a good way to rbind the separate queries into a single table. For the sake of maintaining speed, I don't want to pull the queries into the local environment. Is there a way to accomplish that?

For what it's worth, I've tried collecting the queries into tables, but that crashes RStudio every time.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on each table's schema, you might be able to use raw SQL to do this:

```r
db <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
DBI::dbWriteTable(db, "mt1", mtcars[1:3,], create = TRUE)
DBI::dbWriteTable(db, "mt2", mtcars[4:6,], create = TRUE)
```

With this data, we can see each table individually with the "normal" database `tbl` connector:

```r
tbl(db, "mt1") %>%
  collect()
# # A tibble: 3 x 11
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
# 2  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
# 3  22.8     4   108    93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
tbl(db, "mt2") %>%
  collect()
# # A tibble: 3 x 11
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  21.4     6   258   110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
# 2  18.7     8   360   175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
# 3  18.1     6   225   105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
```

We can use raw SQL as here:

```r
tbl(db, sql("select * from mt1 union all select * from mt2")) %>%
  filter(cyl != 6) %>%
  collect()
# # A tibble: 2 x 11
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  22.8     4   108    93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
# 2  18.7     8   360   175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
```